# Matlab - filtering big arrays with memory mapped files

Tags: matlab

I am using the signal processing toolbox to generate a bandpass filter. I have a large data file (53 gb) of sampled (I/Q) signal that I need feed through the filter. All the signal processing examples I have seen so far are working on (in-memory) arrays. Would they work on memory mapped files as well? Is there another stream abstraction that is more suitable for this purpose.

Thanks

Comment: Try it with a smaller array and find out?